# Quick way to add and concatenate bits

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I've never learned how to do binary arithmetic and was wondering if there was a straightforward technique to doing the following things in your head:

1. Add bits.
2. Concatenate bits.
3. Read bit values into decimal form.

For (1), just being able to do:

```
 101011
+   101
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾
 ??????
```

For (2), instead of *add*, *concatenate*:

```
101011 + 101 = 101011101 ? how to determinal decimal value
```

What I'm doing now is starting from the right, just walking through the bits until I get to about #4 and it gets too complicated lol. I go `00 = 0, 01 = 1, 10 = 2, 11 = 3, ..?`.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you are just adding with carry like in base $10$.  Start from the bottom and add each column.  For 2, just recite one number after the other.  For 3, it helps to memorize the powers of $2$.  A fair number of people know them at least up to $2^{16}=65536$.  Then you have to add in base $10$ the powers that have a $1$ in them.  I would start from the least significant bit as the numbers stay small longer, but I don't know of a royal road.  For your example $101011101=1+4+8+16+64+256=349$ where I did the addition in my head.  It helped to have the number written down so I could point at it and keep my place.  It also helps not to have to compute that the highest bit is worth $256$.